# stages vs. frequency analysis of ring oscillator

Tags: oscillator, nmos, inverting-amplifier, not-gate, positive-feedback

I am currently working on ring oscillators and have stumbled across the following doubt.

Upon practical analysis of CS-amplifier based ring oscillators on hspice(the not gates are comprised of CS amplifiers rather than CMOS circuits.), I have obtained that the time period of oscillation as almost linearly proportional to the number of stages (not gates involved in making the ring oscillator) from the smallest number of stages which can be used.

But, theoretically analyzing like in a few places where they invoked barkhausen's criterion, the time period is inversely proportional to tan(pi/n), with n being the number of stages. I am enclosing one of such examples where they used this method. [Click here to view the example](http://class.ece.iastate.edu/vlsi2/docs/Papers%20Done/2001-08-MSCAS-HC.pdf). Though I can understand linearity at a higher number of stages if this result were true, I obtained linearity from 3 stages onward, which is a bit strange if this were true. Also, it doesn't seem to do with small channel effects as I have tried with channel lengths of both 30nm and 180nm and it still appeared to be true.

I would like to understand why there is this difference in results. Why is it linear for this sort of circuits as well?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What linearity are you asking about? Are you asking why time period is linear to the number of stages?